# ydata_profiling ProfileReport - AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.cbook' has no attribute 'mplDeprecation'

Tags: matplotlib, attributeerror

I am trying to use ProfileReport from ydata_profiling on my dataset. I am working with a virtual environment for my project.
So, in my venv I installed pandas and ydata_profiling.
Then, I use the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from ydata_profiling import ProfileReport
```

(load df using pd.read_csv)

```
profile = ProfileReport(df)
profile
```

I get the following error:

AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.cbook' has no attribute 'mplDeprecation'

I already tried the following:

1. re-installing matplotlib using pip uninstall and pip install matplotlib
2. re-installing ydata-profiling using pip uninstall and pip install ydata-profiling
3. removing all matplotlib folders from my ..venv\lib\site-packages and reinstalling matplotlib using pip
4. upgrading pip, matplotlib, and ydata-profiling

None of the above solved the error.

Any other suggestions on how to solve this error?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: `mplDeprecation` was removed at Matplotlib v3.8, which was just released https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/prev_api_changes/api_changes_3.8.0.html#removals.  I suggest to open a GitHub issue in ydata_profiling to ask them to stop using it.  In the meantime, try downgrading to Matplotlib v3.7.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to make it run by using the following packages configuration:

- matplotlib = ">=3.2,<=3.7.3"
- ydata-profiling = "^4.4,<4.5"

I am using poetry to install all dependencies.
One suggestion would be to look at the requirements of ydata-profiling and install explicitly the packages on your environment.
See https://github.com/ydataai/ydata-profiling/blob/develop/requirements.txt